# SQL PLSQL How to create a lookup on the values taken from the string column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am noobie in PL/SQL and I am struggling with the problem below

My code is like:

```
select view1.col1 from view1
```

`Col1` is the string column. The query retrieves following 2 records.

```
view1.col1
-----------------
Foo [40] boo boo foo [11] loo [abc]
Loo [2] foo foo [a31] foo boo [32]
```

there is another dictionary table for the numeric values present in the view1.col1

table 2

```
ID|Description|
1 | A
2 | G2
3 | C4
32| EE2
11| AA2
40| U1
99| ZZ6
```

I have another table which I wished to join in order to replace the only the numeric values in brackets [] in my example numbers [40], [11], [2], [32] with the descriptive value from table2.col2

I wished result of my code to retrieve

```
-----------------
Foo U1 boo boo foo AA2 loo [abc]
Loo G2 foo foo [a31] foo boo EE2
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  This can be done using a recursive CTE.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty tough problem for a beginner in PL/SQL. It requires several Oracle built-ins to get the right answer.

Anyway, here is a function which does it. It uses regular expressions to count, find and substitute the placeholders. Consequently performance may not be brilliant but it should be acceptable.

```
create or replace function substitution (p_str in varchar2) 
    return varchar2
as
    rv varchar2(4000);
    cnt pls_integer;
    l_id t2.id%type;
    l_sub t2.description%type;
begin
    rv := p_str;
    cnt := regexp_count(p_str, '\[([[:digit:]]+)\]');
    if cnt > 0 then
        for idx in 1..cnt loop
            l_id := to_number(rtrim(ltrim( regexp_substr(p_str, '\[([[:digit:]]+)\]', 1, idx ), '['),']'));
            select description 
            into l_sub
            from t2
            where id = l_id;
            rv := regexp_replace(rv, '\[([[:digit:]]+)\]', l_sub, 1, idx );
        end loop;
    end if;
    return rv;
end;
/
```

You call it like this:

```
select col1 as old_col
       , substitution(col1) as new_col
from view1;
```